# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on app.js:57

Tags: javascript

How to fix error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on app.js:57**

I have file js `app.js` with line code here:

```
    url = 'https://siayi.github.io/website-desa/sites.json';
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    count = new WebsiteCounter(json);
    $("#total").html(count.count);
    $("#kecamatan").html(count.kecamatan);
    $("#kabkot").html(count.kabkot);
    console.log(count);
    $(".render-bar").toggle();
    tables = new WebsiteTable(json);
    $.each(tables, function(key,table) {
      $("#tables").append(table);
    });
});


function WebsiteTable(data) {
  var tables = [];
  var headers = ["Desa", "Kecamatan", "Kabupaten/Kota"];
  var formatted = {
  "Aceh": [],
  "Sumatera Utara": [],
  "Sumatera Barat": [],
  "Riau": [],
  "Papua Barat": []
  };

  $.each(data, function(key,site) {
    formatted[site.provinsi].push([site.title, site.kecamatan, site.kabkot, site.url])
  });
```

Comment: In `$.each` func, **formatted** is null. Check if key site.provinsi exists in every loop. And show us the console log, if you can.

Comment: here is my console log:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:57)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:368)
    at new WebsiteTable (app.js:56)
    at Object.success (app.js:9)
    at fire (jquery.js:3305)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3435)
    at done (jquery.js:9242)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9484)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to push element into an Object, which is not possible, try declaring you array before you push in it and use for( of ) loop instead.

```js
    var url = 'https://siayi.github.io/website-desa/sites.json';
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    var tables = new WebsiteTable(json);
});


function WebsiteTable(data) {
  var tables = [];
  var headers = ["Desa", "Kecamatan", "Kabupaten/Kota"];
  var formatted = {
  "Aceh": [],
  "Sumatera Utara": [],
  "Sumatera Barat": [],
  "Riau": [],
  "Papua Barat": [],
   site: []
  };
  
  for(var site of data){
    var obj = {
      kabkot: site.kabkot,
      kecamatan: site.kecamatan,
      provinsi: site.provinsi,
      title: site.title,
      url: site.url
    }
    
    formatted.site.push(obj)
   
  }
  
  console.log(formatted.site)
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```